# How to correctly update the text value of an input element in a d3.js transition

Tags: javascript, events, input, d3.js, transition

I've been trying, step by step, to convert some very nice but static & non-d3 [code](https://github.com/saebekassebil/teoria/tree/master/examples) for dynamic animation in a d3.js visualisation.

(Though not directly relevant to this problem, the original code 'simply' -haha- accepts a user-supplied chordname such as 'Amaj7', breaks it down into it's component notes and displays the associated waveforms. I'm trying to create an transition-driven animation based on an array of chordnames.)

For my part, for each **successful** code update (to a d3.js friendly version) achieved, the source code was saved to act as a working comparison with the next.

In the current update to the code, I've hit a glitch trying to incorporate a transition. The transition itself is well proven, and (by means of logging) can be seen to fire as expected.

During the transition, the desired attribute value changes (the next chordname to be handled, and the goal of the immediate transition) are failing. Comparing the previous (working) version with the current:

**Initial creation, common to both, but in a separate file and so element is accessible only via the DOM**

```
var input = container
.append("input")
.attr("class", wavebase.animation_type + "_input")
.attr("id", "chordinput")
.attr("type", "text")
.attr("value","Amaj7");
```

**Old**

```
var input = document.getElementById('chordinput');

input.addEventListener('change', inputChanged, false);
inputChanged.call(input);
```

and (pre-transition):

```
input.setAttribute("value", (waveplot.chordname + "\x0A")); 
inputChanged.call(input);
```

Let's be clear: **the above works**.

**New**

```
var input = container
.select("#chordinput")

input.on('change', inputChanged, false);
inputChanged.call(input);
```

Later, neither this:

```
input
.transition()
.text(function() {
    return (waveplot.chordname + "\x0A");
})
```

..nor this:

```
input
.transition()
.attr("value", function() {
    return (waveplot.chordname + "\x0A");
});
```

..nor variants minus the return character ("\x0A") result in update of the input element's value field. waveplot.chordname is, incidentally, always correctly defined.

Given that not even the original Amaj7 is not recognised in the new code, my gut feeling is that the problem lies with the line

```
input.on('change', inputChanged, false);
```

Clearly, with transitions in play, my aim is to trap multiple events using this line. What am I failing to do, or doing wrong? Must I for example use a different trigger (neither 'submit' nor 'click' have any impact), use d3.dispatch(), or even map each event to it's own ('change.n') handler?

Note: much as I'd like to demo this in the likes of a jsfiddle, the whole thing is embedded in a framework, aka for the moment impractical..

Thanks
Thug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here, neither of which are directly related to d3.  However, there are also some d3-related things to be aware of as you fix your code, so I've indicated them in italics below.

First, setting `.text()` won't work on an `<input>`, because it changes the `.textContent` property (which is ignored -- input elements are empty).

*Even if you used `transition().text()` on a valid text container element, you wouldn't see a "transition" -- the text would just instantaneously change after the transition delay.*

Second, the `value` *attribute* of an input is **not** the same as the `value` *property* (i.e. `element.value`).  The attribute (which is what you'd include in the markup) defines the *initial* value for the input element, before any user *or* script interaction.  Changing it after the page is loaded has no effect.  The property, in contrast, defines the current value of the field, regardless of whether you change it in the script or whether the user changes it by typing.

See this fiddle (which only uses plain Javascript, not d3):
http://fiddle.jshell.net/FVF29/

```
var i = document.getElementById("i");
i = i;
i.setAttribute("value", "Stuff");
i.value="Good Stuff";
i.setAttribute("value", "Other Stuff");
```

Neither `setAttribute` call affects the display -- the text box contains "Good Stuff" -- although if you check the DOM you'll see that the attribute has been changed.

Although it's not often used, d3 has a method for changing element properties for the elements in a selection, [`selection.property(propertyName, valueOrFunction)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#property).  However, there is no equivalent function for transitions.

You could make a valid feature request that there *should* be a `transition.property()` function.  Based on your example, I can certainly see a use for it -- maybe you have a number slider or color input, and you want the displayed value to change smoothly instead of instantaneously jumping to the value you're setting it.

*However, that still wouldn't work well in your case.  Assuming the property transition function was implemented the same as an attribute or style transition, the default transition for a string value breaks the string into number and non-number segments.  The non-number segments change immediately, the numbers transition.  Which would be weird and random if you were changing from "Cmin6" to "Amaj7" -- you'd end up with a chord like "Amaj6.569087098608760876"!*

In conclusion:  I have no idea why you want to use a transition to change the text field, or what you expect the in-between values to be.  If you have a clear idea of how you want in-between values to be calculated, use a custom tween function that directly sets `this.value`.  (For an example of how to do this, see the fiddle I created for [this answer, which uses a custom tween to set `this.textContent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002417/d3-use-of-the-name-argument-in-transition-tween/25003358#25003358).)  Otherwise, skip the transition and just use:

```
input.property("value", waveplot.chordname);
```

Comment: The reason for the transition acting directly on the the text input field (and not simply activating the background wave-plotting function) is that I would like a user to be able to enter, visualize (and ultimately hear) their own, substitute chords while stepping through a chord progression). Btw, I might have fought with this for days: fantastic answer.

Comment: For the meantime, I have been able to move forward. Will document the final solution once I have the animation working in all respects.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Chord wave forms is a fun visualization that I've been meaning to try myself, but never got around to it.